# Problem with not allowed to use Boolean as a data type

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Sub-class for a program that creates a list with different objects.

One of my sub-classes is named "Jewelry". Here I need to specify if the material is "gold" or "silver". The different material has a different value. (Gold = 2000, Silver= 700) Im not allowed to use Boolean. Im a big beginner so sorry for the "easy" question. You guys have any tips? much appreciated. Code:

```
public class Jewellery extends Valuable  {
private int numberOfJewels;
private String material;
private double value;

    public Jewellery(String name, int numberOfJewels, String material) {
    super(name);

    this.material = material.valueOf(material);
    this.numberOfJewels = numberOfJewels;
}

public int getNumberOfJewels(){
 return numberOfJewels;
}


public String getMaterial() {
    return material;
}

public double getValue(){
    return value;
}


public double getValuePlusVAT() {
    return value();
}


public String toString(){
    return getName() + " " + this.getMaterial() + " " + getValuePlusVAT();
}
```

}

Comment: Your snippet doesn't mention any booleans though

Comment: You can use enum for it.

Comment: Okay I think enum material will work! thanks!

Comment: Or you can just use an int. Value 0 = false and 1 = true.

Comment: material needs to be a string. Thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

The fast answer can be... use a strings SWITCH then.
The elaborated one is keep a enum with pairs material/value so is more flexible, maintainable and reusable around the application

Comment: Much appreciated! Thanks